# How to OrderBy HasManyThrough Relation specific column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have tables: Locations, Customers, CustomerReview.

Location:

```
public function reviews() {
 return $this->hasManyThrough('App\CustomerReview', 'App\Customer');
}
```

Customer:

```
public function reviews() {
return $this->hasMany('App\CustomerReview');
}
```

CustomerReview

```
public function customer() {
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
}

public function location() {
   return $this->hasOneThrough('App\Location', 'App\Customer');
}
```

In my controller, I have a sort function that takes a query that's being built and determines if it should add an `orderBy` statement. On a specific request on Locations, I need to orderBy a column found on CustomerReview.

How can I orderBy a relation that is hasManyThrough?

Trying something like this:

```
$locations = $locations->with(
                        [
                            'reviews' => function($query) use ($order) {
                                $query->orderBy('nps', $order);
                            }
                        ]
                    );
```

For some reason, this doesn't numerically sort correctly. This is an integer and nullable field in the database.

When I sort (no matter the order), I get results like `6,6,5,5,7,6,5,5` etc. The null values are at the end though

Comment: Ordering inside of `with()` will not affect the parent model. You'll need to use a `join()` for that.

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset should have all you need :) It's a standard `join()` on the `CustomerReview` table, followed by an `orderBy()` on `CustomerReview.nps`. Edit; sorry, likely 2 joins, since there's a Customer table in there too. Try to write the basic query in SQL, using joins in a SQL editor, and translate those to your Model.

Comment: Ok thank you! I did not think I need to use a join statement since I added the `hasManyThrough` relation.